# Why I can’t run exe file on other pc

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I had created with tkinter an application.

this application (python.py) contains a button, by clicking on the button it calls scripts (scripts that I have already created before) and executes them.

I was able to convert python.py to python.exe with pyinstaller (pyinstaller --onefile python.py)
after this step I put my python.exe and **pycache** and all the scripts (with extensions py) that I should use on my application in a single folder and open the folder in NSIS … so you can send it to another user who doesn't have python

On other pc : the application opens but as soon as I click on the button to have the execution of the scripts I have an error

> > > python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft store, or disable this shortcut from settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

I fix it with disable app python on manage app execution aliases. (I don’t know if it correct), but I tried to run it again and I have this error

> python’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

yet everything works fine on my pc

knowing that I work on windows

maybe i forgot a step?

Comment: How does the button call another script? By running `python` from command?

Answer (score 0):

Python interpreter is not installed on the target PC. Bundle your executable with all dependency libraries necessary to run your application on any windows PC. Also note that your windows version matters too.